# Azure AD B2C Login Problems

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying out the sample code on GitHub called active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi and when I run it against the AD B2C directory in the sample it works fine but I'm having an issue trying it out against my own AD B2C directory. I get the following error:

> The application with ID 'xxx' cannot get an ID token either because the openid scope was not requested or the application is not authorized for it

Isn't the openid scope included automatically? I setup a Web App and a Web API app as per the instructions provided. When I look at the scopes that the Web App has access to, the openid scope is not listed there. Is this something I need to add manually?

Comment: Can you please add some more info on the library youre using, link to the code sample, and if possible a Correlation ID from the failed request?

Comment: I used the code as-is from the following Git repository.  [Git Code Repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi)  Correlation ID: a225593c-e462-4cad-865a-3b19d0d673fd

Answer (score -1, accepted):

openid scope is not included automatically. It should be present by default in the sample, but if it was removed, then the request will fail.

Comment: Thanks Parakh. It seems at some point I deleted the default API access that was added when I created the web app. That default API access had the 2 default scopes in it. I didn't see any way of adding it back so I ended up having to delete the Web API and Web App applications I added and regenerate them from scratch. This got me past that error and logged in.

Answer (score 7):

When we change the API permission for an app, the openid permission gets overwritten. We can re-enable it if this happens. The option will be available at API Permissions blade under https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade.

Open the API Permissions at the above link, Add a Permission, Select Microsoft Graph --> Select Openid and save. There you are! :)

Comment: This is what i was looking for, saved my day

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the openID step outlined above, also do the below:

Go to the API access under the Application in B2C for the app in question and add a permission against this same app saying "access this app on behalf of the signed in user".

No other steps needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue was with app registrations > API Permissions. When adding permissions in the Request API permissions screen, make sure you select "Delegated permissions: Your application needs to access the API as the signed-in user."

If you selected the other option, then recreate your configuration and try again.